# Unicity of Neumann homogeneous boundary value problem

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, boundary-value-problem

I would like to show that the following problem has only the trivial solution :

Let be $\Omega\subset \mathbb{R}^n$ open an Lipschitz bounded, and $c$ continous and positive on $\bar{\Omega}$, s.t $\exists x_0\in\Omega,\, c(x_0)>0$. The problem then states
$$
\begin{cases}\Delta u=cu & \textrm{in }\Omega\\\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}=0 &\textrm{on } \partial \Omega\end{cases}
$$
with $\partial\nu$ the normal derivative.

I already shown that if $u>0$ for some $x\in\Omega$ then, $u>0$ on all $\Omega$ by subharmonicity, but I cannot figure out how to hanlde de $c(x_0)>0$ which should gives the conclusion.

All help welcome !

Answer (score 1):

I finally found it. In fact it is just an application of the divergence Theorem :

\begin{align*}
 \Delta u=cu\implies\int_{\Omega}\Delta u=\int_\Omega cu 
\end{align*}

But $\Delta u=\textrm{div}(\nabla u)$ and then $\int_{\Omega}\Delta u=\oint_{\partial \Omega}\nabla u\cdot\nu=\oint_{\partial \Omega}\frac{\partial u}{\partial \nu}u=0$.

Then
\begin{align*}
 \int_\Omega cu =0
\end{align*}
But by continuity of $c$, there is some open neighbourhood $V$ of $x_0$ such that $c>0$ on $V$, and $u>0$ on $\Omega$ by subharmonicity. Combined with $c\geq 0$ on $\Omega$, this gives
$$
 0<\int_V cu \leq \int_\Omega cu
$$

which is an obvious contradiction.